# Haxe Reflection Method to Access a Static Field?

Tags: reflection, static, haxe

I'm looking for a way to use reflection to get and set static fields of a `Class`. Is that possible, or is that too dynamic for Haxe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, if it's too static for Reflection :)? No, it is not

```
var cl = Type.resolveClass("MyClass");
trace(Reflect.fields(cl));
trace(Reflect.field(cl, "field"));
trace(Reflect.setField(cl, "field", 0));
```

Comment: In Javascript, `Reflect.fields()` will return `$field` here. It looks like the field name as understood by Reflect is not always the human readable name of the field.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can get all static fields of a class using `Type.getClassFields()` (or `Type.getInstance()` for instance ones). Take a look here : https://api.haxe.org/Type.html